# joining 3 table with UNION with different columns

Tags: php, mysql, union-all

I am trying to display Income and Expense Month wise in my PHP CRM Script. It is working for 2 tables. But Now i want to combine one more table's amount with expense data. I am not getting how to do it.

Here is my query for extracting Income and Expense data

```
SELECT
    YEAR(v.paid_date) AS Yr,
    MONTHNAME(v.paid_date) AS Month,
    SUM(IF(v.IncomeOrExpense = 'Income', v.paid_amount, 0)) AS Income,
    SUM(IF(v.IncomeOrExpense = 'Expense', v.paid_amount, 0)) AS Expense
FROM in_exp v
GROUP BY Yr, Month
ORDER BY Yr DESC, Month DESC
```

And i have created a view for this:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `in_exp`  AS  select `r`.`invoice_id` AS `invoice_id`,`r`.`customer` AS `customer`,`r`.`paid_amount` AS `paid_amount`,`r`.`paid_date` AS `paid_date`,`r`.`comments` AS `comments`,`l`.`company` AS `company`,'Income' AS `IncomeOrExpense` from (`receipt` `r` join `leads` `l` on((`r`.`customer` = `l`.`id`))) union all select `p`.`invoice_id` AS `invoice_id`,`p`.`vendor` AS `vendor`,`p`.`paid_amount` AS `paid_amount`,`p`.`paid_date` AS `paid_date`,`p`.`comments` AS `comments`,`v`.`name` AS `name`,'Expense' AS `Expense` from (`payments` `p` join `vendor` `v` on((`p`.`vendor` = `v`.`id`))) union all select `e`.`eid` AS `eid`,`e`.`user` AS `user`,`e`.`paid_amount` AS `paid_amount`,`e`.`paid_date` AS `paid_date`,`e`.`comments` AS `comments`,`u`.`firstname` AS `firstname`,'Expense' AS `Expense` from (`expense_pay` `e` join `users` `u` on((`e`.`user` = `u`.`id`))) ;
```

Now i want to add `SUM(IF(v.IncomeOrExpense = 'Expense', v.paid_amount, 0)) AS Expense` with one more table (expenses) Amount which has vendor and amount.

Can somebody suggest me how to achieve this? I cannot change the table structure for expenses table as it is connected to so many queries and tables already.

Comment: Any reason why you are selecting a load of columns on the view which are not used in the final query?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the select works correctly for the the third union then change the literal 'expense' to something else 'expenseV' say and add the statement

```
SUM(IF(v.IncomeOrExpense = 'ExpenseV', v.paid_amount, 0)) AS Expense
```

to your query